# How can use different redis connection in laravel

Tags: laravel, redis

I am creating a laravel package, in this pacakge i need to save some data in redis, but i want this package to use different redis connection, so that if they can setup the redis details credential in package's config file and will use this connection for this package. I want to give freedom to use different redis connection to the package user.

If you have any idea how can i achieve this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a [section in the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/redis) called

> Using Multiple Redis Connections

To change your connection call

```
$redis = Redis::connection('my-connection');
```

You can add and remove connections from config during runtime with the [config helper](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-config).

```
config(['database.redis.new-connection' => [  
        'host' => '127.0.0.1',
        'password' => 'secret',
        'port' => '6379',
        'database' => 0
      ] 
]);
```